# How to make this Postgres query faster?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL. I do one table aggregate compute.
I use core four cloumn. My data formate is like this.

```
----------------------------------------------
line_no |holiday_flag| passenger_up|plan_date
----------------------------------------------
1           0           22          2019-02-02
1           0           15          2019-02-02
1           0           14          2019-02-02
1           1           0           2019-02-03
1           1           11          2019-02-03
1           1           3           2019-02-03
1           1           15          2019-02-03
1           3           4           2019-02-17
1           3           1           2019-02-17
1           3           3           2019-02-17
1           3           4           2019-02-17
1           3           2           2019-02-17
1           3           0           2019-02-17
1           3           1           2019-02-17
1           2           0           2019-02-02
1           2           0           2019-02-02
1           2           0           2019-02-02
1           2           3           2019-02-02
```

I want sum the passenger_up by holiday_flag.The holiday_flag has type 0,1,2,3.The holiday_flag (0,2) aggregate in one group.The final holiday_flag type is 0,1,3.
My final result is like this.

```
-----------------------------------
line_no |holiday_flag| passenger_up
-----------------------------------
1           0           4858
1           1           2176
1           3           4638
-----------------------------------
```

My sql now is like this.

```
SELECT
    line_no,
    holiday_flag,
    round(passenger_up / day_count) as passenger_up
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            line_no,
            holiday_flag,
            SUM (passenger_up) AS passenger_up,
            SUM (day_count) AS day_count
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    line_no,
                    CASE
                WHEN holiday_flag = 0
                OR holiday_flag = 2 THEN
                    0
                ELSE
                    holiday_flag
                END AS holiday_flag,
                SUM (passenger_up) AS passenger_up,
                COUNT (DISTINCT plan_date) AS day_count
            FROM
                ext_passenger_flow_tag
            WHERE
                line_no = 1
            AND plan_date >= '2019-01-31'
            AND plan_date <= '2019-02-20'
            GROUP BY
                line_no,
                holiday_flag
            ) AS B
        GROUP BY
            B.line_no,
            B.holiday_flag
    ) AS C
```

My EXPLAIN output is like this.

```
Subquery Scan on c  (cost=4456.55..4456.72 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=19.316..19.322 rows=3 loops=1)
  Output: c.line_no, c.holiday_flag, round((c.passenger_up / c.day_count), 0)
  Buffers: shared hit=372
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4456.55..4456.66 rows=4 width=72) (actual time=19.312..19.316 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: b.line_no, b.holiday_flag, sum(b.passenger_up), sum(b.day_count)
        Group Key: b.line_no, b.holiday_flag
        Buffers: shared hit=372
        ->  Sort  (cost=4456.55..4456.56 rows=4 width=24) (actual time=19.305..19.305 rows=4 loops=1)
              Output: b.line_no, b.holiday_flag, b.passenger_up, b.day_count
              Sort Key: b.line_no, b.holiday_flag
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              Buffers: shared hit=372
              ->  Subquery Scan on b  (cost=4359.02..4456.51 rows=4 width=24) (actual time=17.501..19.279 rows=4 loops=1)
                    Output: b.line_no, b.holiday_flag, b.passenger_up, b.day_count
                    Buffers: shared hit=372
                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4359.02..4456.47 rows=4 width=26) (actual time=17.500..19.276 rows=4 loops=1)
                          Output: ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_no, CASE WHEN ((ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag = 0) OR (ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag = 2)) THEN 0 ELSE (ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag)::integer END, sum(ext_passenger_flow_tag.passenger_up), count(DISTINCT ext_passenger_flow_tag.plan_date), ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag
                          Group Key: ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_no, ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag
                          Buffers: shared hit=372
                          ->  Sort  (cost=4359.02..4378.50 rows=7790 width=14) (actual time=15.231..16.075 rows=7899 loops=1)
                                Output: ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_no, ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag, ext_passenger_flow_tag.passenger_up, ext_passenger_flow_tag.plan_date
                                Sort Key: ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag
                                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 563kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=372
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.ext_passenger_flow_tag  (cost=2174.75..3855.50 rows=7790 width=14) (actual time=9.908..12.697 rows=7899 loops=1)
                                      Output: ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_no, ext_passenger_flow_tag.holiday_flag, ext_passenger_flow_tag.passenger_up, ext_passenger_flow_tag.plan_date
                                      Recheck Cond: ((ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_no = 1) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_subno = 1) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.updown = 1) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.plan_date >= '2019-01-31'::date) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.plan_date <= '2019-02-20'::date) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.interval_flag = 2))
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=86
                                      Buffers: shared hit=372
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ext_pf_tag_index1  (cost=0.00..2172.80 rows=7790 width=0) (actual time=9.876..9.876 rows=7899 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_no = 1) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.line_subno = 1) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.updown = 1) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.plan_date >= '2019-01-31'::date) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.plan_date <= '2019-02-20'::date) AND (ext_passenger_flow_tag.interval_flag = 2))
                                            Buffers: shared hit=286
Planning time: 0.533 ms
Execution time: 19.450 ms
```

I don't know how to optimize the sql. 
My aim is the query sql run less then 100ms.

Comment: Where is your `EXPLAIN` output?

Comment: 19ms is about 5 times faster than your expected 100ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query already takes less than 100 milliseconds.

First, simplify your SQL statement:

```
SELECT line_no,                                                             
       CASE WHEN holiday_flag = 2                                           
            THEN 0                                                             
            ELSE holiday_flag                                                  
       END AS holiday_flag,                                                    
       round(CAST(sum(passenger_up)                                            
                  AS double precision) /                                       
             CAST(count(DISTINCT plan_date)                                    
                  AS double precision)) AS passenger_up                        
FROM ext_passenger_flow_tag                                                    
WHERE line_no = 1                                                              
  AND plan_date BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-31' AND DATE '2019-02-20'                
GROUP BY line_no, holiday_flag;
```

I notice that the execution plan is for a different query, could you fix that?

It is hard to advise further without knowing the actual execution plan.

I would also like to know the definition of the index to see if it is optimal.